# adDidDismissFullScreenContent - How do you determine if the ad was an Interstitial or Rewarded?

Tags: swift, admob

I'm using Google AdMob v8 to implement Interstitial ads and Rewarded Ads in the same View Controller.

I need to be able to determine which ad was dismissed, so that I can properly load up another.

```
func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) 
    
    loadRewarded()
    loadInterstitial()
}
```

My progress above is loading both a rewarded and interstitial no matter which ad was dismissed.

**How can I determine which ad (either an Interstitial or Rewarded) was dismissed?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) 
    
    print("Ad dismiss full screen ad")
    if type(of: ad) == GADInterstitialAd.self {
      print("InterstitialAd")
    }else if  type(of: ad) == GADRewardedAd.self {
      print("RewardedAd")
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you determine type in Objective C?

Comment: @Peter - I have not tried.. but should be similar... Have you tried using isKindOfClass ? If that works.. update it as answer so that it will be helpful