# Any way to get reward after the Ads have been finished playing

Tags: swift

I want to get reward after Ads have been playing finished, now I will get reward when I close the Ads, I don't want this. Here is my code now, in GADFullScreenContentDelegate:

```
func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
    print("Rewarded ad dismissed.")
    // function which can get reward. 
    getReward()
}
```

I don't know where I have to put this function in, is there any delegate that can know the Ads have been playing finished?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adDidDismissFullScreenContent - How do you determine if the ad was an Interstitial or Rewarded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66642935/addiddismissfullscreencontent-how-do-you-determine-if-the-ad-was-an-interstiti)

Comment: Isn't the ad finished playing once it's closed? Do you mean you want it to fully complete without the user closing it early? I think that would be a very specific type of ad (called a rewarded ad I think). The link above probably explains this, although I didn't go to it myself.

Comment: Thank you guys, I have solved it. I wrote my getReward func in present(fromRootViewController:, userDidEarnRewardHandler:), it works for me, only when I watched the Ads completely